# sending json payload to php server from advance rest client

Tags: php, json, rest

I want to send json payload to my PHP webservice. I am testing on advance rest client. I already search similar answers. But it is not helping me. 
I am sending this json to my php service which is running on localhost.

```
{
"name":"XXXX",
"password":"YYYYY"
}
```

I changed the content-type from dropdown to application/json.
However sending value as form parameter from advance rest client works fine.But this is not what i want.

My php code is

```
$name= isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : "";
    $pass= isset($_POST['pass']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']) : "";

    echo $name;
    echo $pass;
```

but it is always printing the blank value.
I am new to php but found this is the way to receive post params.

Comment: $_POST will only be populated if the request is send as `Content-Type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` – if you send it using any other content type, then you need to read the data from `php://input` (f.e. using `file_get_contents`), and then parse it yourself.

Comment: are you posting json data to your php webservice ? or please tell how you are sending it.

Comment: @SashantPardeshi yes i sent json data in body of request. and the problem was in php code. Now I got the solution using above answers.

Comment: @CBroe ya got the point thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if any one else facing same issue. To read the json data sent in the request body we can use this method

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($request_body);
    $name = isset($data->name) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data->name) : "";
    echo $name
}
```

Now it will give the correct value.